# How to merge two DateObject list together?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, date-and-time

I have two huge lists of flight data(one is around 7 million observations and another is around 1 million).

The first one contains the city names, the departure time(accurate to the minute), and some other variables.

The second one contains the city names, dates, and the weather.

I want to merge the two lists by date and city name. For example:

```
list1 = {{"City A", DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}]}, {"City B", 
   DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}]}, {"City C", DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}]}}
```

```
list2 = {{"City A", "Cloudy", DateObject[{2019}]}, {"City B", "Sunny", 
   DateObject[{2020}]}, {"City B", "Rainy", DateObject[{2021}]}, {"City C", "Sunny",
    DateObject[{2019}]}}
```

The output would be like this:

```
{{"City A", "Cloudy", DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}]}, {"City B", "Sunny", 
  DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}]}, {"City C", "Sunny", DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}]}}
```

Is there an efficient way to merge them?

Comment: It is worthwhile pointing out that lists you have given, do not quite reflect the description of the problem. Your second list -list2- does not have a city name, for example. Perhaps you would like to update or explain a little bit. Try to play around with Join, GatherBy in the meantime

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 Sorry, I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Join by `year`

For each year in the `list2` item, we get the detailed date by find items with similar `year` in `list1`:

```
list1 = {{"City A", DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}]}, {"City B", 
    DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}]}, {"City C", DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}]}};

list2 = {{1, "Cloudy", DateObject[{2019}]}, {1, "Sunny", 
    DateObject[{2020}]}, {1, "Rainy", DateObject[{2021}]}, {2, 
    "Sunny", DateObject[{2019}]}};
```

Group `list1` items by year, so we could later use indexing for each year:

```
ls1 = GroupBy[list1, #[[-1, 1, 1]] &];
```

Finally:

```
MapIndexed[
    With[{temp = ls1[#1[[-1, 1, 1]]]}, 
      If[MissingQ@temp, 
       Nothing, #1[[;; 2]]~Append~temp[[First@#2, 2]]]] &, #] & /@ 
  GatherBy[list2, #[[-1, 1, 1]] &] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

Result (Timezone information had been removed from the result):

```
{{1, "Cloudy", DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}, "Day"]},
 {2, "Sunny", DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}, "Day"]},
 {1, "Sunny", DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}, "Day"]}}
```

Notes:

- The input's order is different from the result.
- Number of items with the same year in `list1` should be greater or equal to `list2`.
- For your case which involves millions of records, I don't think it would be efficient.

### Update - join by `city name`

For each `city name` in `list2` we will get the detailed date from `list1` by finding items that match `city name` and `year`:

```
list1 = {{"City A", DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}]}, {"City B", 
    DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}]}, {"City C", DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}]}};

list2 = {{"City A", "Cloudy", DateObject[{2019}]}, {"City B", "Sunny",
     DateObject[{2020}]}, {"City B", "Rainy", 
    DateObject[{2021}]}, {"City C", "Sunny", DateObject[{2019}]}};
```

Code:

```
If[Length@# == 1, Nothing, Extract[#, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}}]] & /@
 GatherBy[list1~Join~list2, Extract[#, {{1}, {-1, 1, 1}}] &]
```

Result (Timezone information had been removed from the result):

```
{{"City A", "Cloudy", DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}, "Day"]},
 {"City B", "Sunny", DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}, "Day"]},
 {"City C", "Sunny", DateObject[{2019, 1, 2}, "Day"]}}
```

Notes:

- The code will join items with similar `city name` and `year`, having more than `1` item in each list with similar `city name` and `year` may lead to an unexpected result, month or day doesn't matter (just duplicate a row and see the result)

Comment: Thank You for answering, the lists gives in the question has been corrected to simplify the problem, could you please check it again? Thanks!

Comment: @Charmbracelet answer updated.

Comment: thank you so much, this really helps me!!!